# Incorrect routes appearing valid

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am using path variables in my Route components. Initially, I had

```
<Route path={"/:brand/"} component={HomeContainer} />
```

but I had to change path attribute to

```
path={"/:brand(brandOne|brandTwo)/"}
```

because incorrect URLs appeared to be valid. The code above works for my 2 brand sections.

How would you suggest I do this for my products container as I have many products and I don't want random incorrect URLs to show an empty page with SiteHeader and SiteFooter.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have many params that you want to validate for, you can simply store the valid ones in an array and check for the param while rendering, If the param is not among those, redirect to either 404 or home page

```
render() {
   const { match} = this.props;
   if(!validParams.includes(match.params.brand)) {
      return <Redirect to="/404" />
   } 
   // return normal component here
}
```

Comment: Hmm, unsure about that solution. The URL slugs are based on a dynamic json object. I would need to update the array every time the API was changed.